# React router Link with path name state and data-widget

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using adminLTE tempate for my react js app. I am using react router Link to specified pathname with state like below.

`<Link  className="nav-link text-white" to={{pathname: "/calendar", state: groups: this.state.groups}}}>Calendar</Link>`

Everything is working fine in the above code. But I need to add data-widget="pushmenu" for my sidebar to collapse in mobile devices.

If I use the below code

```
`<Link  data-widget="pushmenu" className="nav-link text-white" to={{pathname: "/calendar", state: groups: this.state.groups}}}>Calendar</Link>`
```

pushmenu widget is working but the calendar componenent is not working. I used higher order like below which is also not working

```
<a data-widget="pushmenu">
<Link>Calendar</Link>
</a>
```

Please help me with this issue

Comment: Why don't you add the ```data-widget``` into to state, and take if from there ?

Comment: data-widget='pushmenu' data api activates jquery plugin(AdminLTE) and the state is used in a different calendar component. Link needs to activate a jquery plugin and load a component